# Send Object as string, not JSON, via Node Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, object

Ok, I want the response to be a plain string, not JSON.

Ex. this object

```js
let obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 1
}
```

Should be returned as

```
"{foo: 'bar', baz: 1}"
```

Instead of

```
{"foo": "bar", "baz": 1}
```

Why? I need to use the string as a link in [quickchart](https://quickchart.io/documentation)

```html
<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?c={type:'line',data:{labels:['January','February', 'March','April', 'May'], datasets:[{label:'Dogs', data: [50,60,70,180,190], fill:false,borderColor:'blue'},{label:'Cats', data:[100,200,300,400,500], fill:false,borderColor:'green'}]}}">
```

The double quotes in JSON break the image link.

Or, maybe suggest a better way.

Comment: JSON is always a string (and `"{foo: 'bar', baz: 1}"` isn't JSON)

Comment: Write your own serialiser, it's not difficult if your object property values are just strings and numbers.

Comment: @Andreas — But not a string in the format the OP is asking for. `"{foo: 'bar', baz: 1}"`, as you said, isn't JSON, but it **is** what the OP wants.

Comment: try to use encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(obj)). Make sure that the response type is 'plain/text'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The double quotes in JSON break the image link.

You have [an XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

The **problem** is that using `"` characters in an attribute value delimited by `"` characters will break the attribute value.

While avoiding using `"` characters in the data is *a* solution, it isn't a good one (largely because avoiding them without breaking other stuff is hard). A better solution is to correctly **escape** them.

```
const json = JSON.stringify(obj);
const url_escaped_json = encodeURIComponent(json);
const img = `<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?c=${url_escaped_json}" alt="...">`;
```

Note that this doesn't use HTML escaping (which would replace `"` with `&quot;`), because you are putting the data into a URL so it needs URL escaping first (and that will replace `"` with `%20` rendering the HTML escaping unneeded).

Comment: Perfection! Thank you for the great explanation. Love the XY problem pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You might leverage a dedicated API for that like [Image-Charts](https://image-charts.com) that handles such encoding issue nicely:

```
https://image-charts.com/chart?cht=lc
&chd=a:50,60,70,180,190|100,200,300,400,500
&chs=900x400
&chdl=Dogs|Cats&chdlp=t&chdls=444444,15
&chxt=x,y
&chxl=0:|January|February|March|April|May
&chg=1,1
&chco=0018F5,377E22
```

[image]

Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.

Answer (score -4):

You can use `JSON.stringify` for this.

```
let obj = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: 1
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

This will convert the object into string.

Comment: A string, yes. The string format the OP is asking for: No.